# jQuery visibility option on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, visibility

I have problem with this JS code. When I started to test it, it is working properly with FF and Chrome but not with IE8.

I guess, something is wrong with IE visiblity property or the mouseover events. I tried everything but I am so deep in here I can't see the whole picture.

How can I make it run properly also in IE. Hate IE :))

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
      var doFadeIn = function() { 
         $('.aboutme').css({ opacity:0, visibility:'visible'}).fadeTo(900,1);
         }; 
         $('layout_aboutme').mouseover(doFadeIn); 
      var doFadeOut = function(){
         $('.aboutme').css({ opacity:0, visibility:'hidden'}).fadeTo(900,1);
         };
         $('layout_aboutme').mouseleave(doFadeOut);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `$('layout_aboutme')` which isn't a valid Element. You probably mean the id `$('#layout_aboutme')` or class `$('.layout_aboutme')`.

ps:
`$(function(){ ... });` is short for `$(document).load(function(){ ... });`

Comment: $('layout_aboutme') is an html tag that I created - no difference with $('p') or $('body') but I tried your solution still not working.

Comment: Seriously, you created `<layout_aboutme>...</layout_aboutme>`? This is quite invalid and won't work in IE (or some others).

Answer (score 0):

i dont get why your assigning variable, anyway..

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.aboutme').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css({ opacity:0, visibility:'visible'}).fadeTo(900,1);
    });
    $('.aboutme').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css({ opacity:0, visibility:'hidden'}).fadeTo(900,1);
    });
});
```

You should also read jerone's comment and sort out your selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I changed the html tags to the div tags with specific ids . It worked.
when it was working with all browsers except IE, I assumed it is all about css styles
but it wasn't.

thanks guys.